# How do you add logic into the following `myApp` haskell function?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-warp

I am still trying to understand how haskell syntax works.  So, here's a dead simple `wai`/`warp` application.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)

myApp _ respond = respond $
    responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "Hello World" 

main = run 3000 myApp
```

If I want to print out some text into `stdout` with `putStrLn` *before* returning the status 200 and "Hello World" plain text, how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myApp` has this type:

```
myApp :: Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

so you can add your own IO action before returning the response like this:

```
myApp _ respond = do putStrLn "processing request"
                     respond $ responseLBS status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "Hello World"
```

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong as this is in fact what I did right from the get-go but it gives me `hellowai.hs:7:5: parse error on input ‘respond’`

Comment: Damn, I realize that my tabs are not configured as space. My bad. This works great.

Comment: Haskell is whitespace sensitive - make sure things line up and do not use tabs. Here is my code: http://lpaste.net/117798